# Handle Http errors with spring integration on int-ws:outbound-gateway

Tags: java, web-services, http, spring-integration

I'm having problems handling http erros on `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`
I tried placing a `error-channel` on `<int:gateway>`, but it doesn't seem to work, because I get unmarshalling exceptions.
 Plus I feel it's not right, http errors should be caught somewhere after the message is received from `<int-ws:outboung-gateway>` 
My messaging system is set up like this: 
`<int:gateway> -> channel -> transformer -> channel -> <int-ws:outboung-gateway>`

Question: what's the right way to catch http errors with spring integration?

**AFTER EDIT**

```
  <int:channel id="checkProcessRequestChannel"/>
  <int:channel id="checkProcessResponseChannel"/>

  <int:channel id="errorChannel"/>

  <!-- channels for connecting to the outbound gateway -->
  <int:channel id="checkProcessOutboundRequestChannel"/>
  <int:channel id="checkProcessOutboundResponseChannel"/>



<int:gateway id="eInvoiceGateway" service-interface="com.iquest.play.integration.einvoice.EInvoiceGateway" error-channel="errorChannel">
    <int:method name="checkProcessByCode" request-channel="checkProcessRequestChannel" reply-channel="checkProcessResponseChannel"/>
<int:gateway>



  <int:transformer ref="eInvoiceTransformer" method="transformCheckProcessRequest" input-channel="checkProcessRequestChannel" output-channel="checkProcessOutboundRequestChannel"/>
  <int:transformer ref="eInvoiceTransformer" method="transformCheckProcessResponse" input-channel="checkProcessOutboundResponseChannel" output-channel="checkProcessResponseChannel"/>



 <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="checkClientByCodeOutboundGW"
                           request-channel="checkProcessOutboundRequestChannel"
                           reply-channel="checkProcessOutboundResponseChannel"
                           marshaller="eInvoiceMarshaller"
                           unmarshaller="eInvoiceMarshaller"
                           destination-provider="eInvoiceUriProvider"
                           message-factory="eInvoiceMessageFactory"
                           />
```

**FIX:**
So, after placing a `error-channel` on the gateway, the thread was getting stuck somewhere. It was a pretty dummy problem, the name of the `service-activator` for gateway error-channel was `errorHandler`, it's probably used by the spring namespace -> changing the bean name solved the problem.

Comment: Are you pertaining to 5xx errors ?

Comment: yes, I need to ignore soap faults and handle just http 5xx errors

Comment: Can you show the flow from int:gateway passing through error-channel?

Comment: I added a `after edit` section

Comment: What you did is correct - the exception is caught by the gateway and sent to the `error-channel`. "...but it doesn't seem to work, because I get unmarshalling exceptions..." - can you explain further? Turn on DEBUG logging and follow the message flow - it should become clear.

Comment: @GaryRussell I've been struggling today all day, I don't know why but the messaging system hangs out somewhere. I'm trying to catch a http exception and wrap it in my custom exception. When I throw the custom exception it doesn't get back in the gateway.. the process hangs somewhere. Can you please take a look at the stack trace ? http://www.pastebucket.com/40573 plus is the current spring-integration set up http://www.pastebucket.com/40575

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything we can do about it; the exception is thrown deep in the `WebServiceTemplate` and SAAJ code, which doesn't handle getting `text/plain` responses. You will have to just handle this exception, but I don't see a way to get access to the status code etc.

Comment: @GaryRussell By handling the exception you mean surround the `gateway.method()` in a `try/catch`? What do you mean text/plain responses (the exception I'm throwing)? I don't need the exact http code, I just want to wrap when I'm getting a HTTP error.. or a connection refused exception.. in my custom exception? Is there a way to do that(except surrounding the gateway call in a try catch), because I want the gateway method to throw a checked exception.

Comment: Use a custom `error-channel` on the inbound gateway; in its flow, add a `<service-activator input-channel="myErrorChannel"/>` to handle the error `void foo(MessagingException bar) throws MyCheckedException {...}`. The MessagingException has 2 properties `failedMessage` - the message at the point the ws gateway was invoked and `cause` the exception the gateway threw. You can introspect both and throw whatever exception you want to the gateway caller.

Comment: what `inbound-gateway`? I'm using a `outbound-gateway`, but I checked, there is no error-channel for that

Comment: @Lulian I believe Gary is referring to your gateway named eInvoiceGateway

Comment: @GaryRussell, so I added a `error-channel="errorChannel"` to the `eInvoiceGateway`, and created a `<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" output-channel="checkProcessResponseChannel" ref="errorHandler"/>`, that's what I did before also.. the problem is, the process is hanging somewhere... the flow doesn't get back to the gateway caller

Comment: @GaryRussell- I solved the problem, the `service-activator` bean was named errorHandler, changing the name helped

Comment: Where you able to get the fault message from response in your errorHandler ?

Answer (score 0):

We can handle http errors in spring integration during unmarshal.

Write a custom unmarshaller and catch the soap fault message.

This article explains clearly how to handle soap fault message.

http://blog.hostmasterzone.com/how-to-unmarshal-soap-fault-in-spring-integration-web-service/

```
 <bean id="hmzJaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
         <property name="contextPaths">
                <list>
                    <value>org.hmz.request.types</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
<bean id="custJaxbUnMarshaller" class="com.jay.hmz.util.CustJaxbUnMarshaller" >
     <property name="contextPaths">
            <list>
                <value>org.hmz.request.types</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int:chain input-channel="channel.in" output-channel="channel.out"> 
         <int:transformer method="transformParentRequestById"><bean class="org.jay.hmz.api.transformers.OrderTransformer"/></int:transformer>
         <int-ws:header-enricher><int-ws:soap-action value="${order.request.uri}"/></int-ws:header-enricher> <int-ws:outbound-gateway interceptors="hmzSecurityInterceptor" mapped-request-headers="GUID, USER_REF" request-callback="hmzWebServiceMessageCallback" unmarshaller="custJaxbUnMarshaller" marshaller="hmzJaxbMarshaller" uri="${order.request.uri}"/> 
         <int:transformer method="transformRetrieveParentOrderResponse"><bean class="org.jay.hmz.api.transformers.OrderTransformer"/></int:transformer> 
     </int:chain>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="requestErrorChannel" output-channel="response.out" ref="requestErrorHandler" method="handleFailedOrderRequest"/>

    <bean id="requestErrorHandler" class="org.jay.hmz.api.errorhandler.RequestErrorHandler"/>

public class CustJaxbUnMarshaller extends Jaxb2Marshaller {

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(Source source, MimeContainer mimeContainer)
            throws XmlMappingException {
        LOGGER.debug("Inside Custom JaxbWrapper unmarshal");
        Object mimeMessage = new DirectFieldAccessor(mimeContainer)
                .getPropertyValue("mimeMessage");
        Object unmarshalObject = null;
        if (mimeMessage instanceof SaajSoapMessage) {
            SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) mimeMessage;
            String faultReason = soapMessage.getFaultReason();
            if (faultReason != null) {
                throw convertJaxbException(new JAXBException(faultReason));
            } else {
                unmarshalObject = super.unmarshal(source, mimeContainer);
            }
        }
        return unmarshalObject;
    }
}
```